# How to extract values inside a JSON array object using Lodash 4?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, lodash

Im using Lodash to get the value from the array object. 
I tried using,

```
let result = _.get(responseFromServer, 'responseFromServer.result');
```

However, I get undefined as the error. I have tried variations of this..but Im unable to extract from, to, amount and result fields from the response.

I get the response from the server as:

```
[
  {
    "question": {
        "from": "UnitA",
        "to": "UnitB",
        "amount": "100"
    },
    "result": 200.45899
  }
]
```

Comment: you seem to be completely ignoring the fact that you have an array. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#get additionally, the variable that the data is stored in doesn't belong in the path you pass to lodash. It isn't part of the data.

Comment: In your case, what you want would be more similar to this example: `_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');` only without the `a`

Comment: @KevinB Yes. It worked. Thanks!
Im new to lodash and it wasnt very clear to me. Your comment actually could be made as an answer since lodash is a very commonly used library and many newbies may face similar issues.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your case you have an array, so first you'll have to specify which index within that array you want to access.

```
let result = _.get(responseFromServer, '[0]');
```

That will give the object, now you just have to specify they key you want from it

```
let result = _.get(responseFromServer, '[0].result');
```